# Why can Visual Studio 2019 not find the Qt include-files?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt5, visual-studio-2019

I'm using the project wizard and am receiving the following error messages:

**E1696 cannot open source file "QtWidgets/QApplication"**

**E1696 cannot open source file "QtWidgets/QMainWindow"**

I added the include-files under **Project ->  Properties... -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories**

as

D:\Qt\Qt5.14.0\5.14.0\msvc2017\include

That is, Visual Studio 2019 resides on C:, while Qt does on D:.

I controlled the actions of Visual Studio 2019 via Process Monitor, and it never showed an attempt to even access a Qt-directory, not to speak of the include file itself (protocol added).

Any ideas on this one?

[Project files.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjUMaEZxLUxyhZwu0wO3Nq2Y5IUTfw?e=3aIAYX)

[Process Monitor log.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjUMaEZxLUxyhZwvZlf7zOjfzJnvag?e=rurMfD)

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems previously with VS19 and the Qt include files. The solution to my problem was that I had to first open VS19 (by itself), then select the "*Open a project or solution*" from the start page.